# What happens to the execution context when I call Thread.new in a Rails/Rack request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say three Rails instances have been spawned and are taking requests.

For each request Thread.new is called a bunch of a times to put some cross cutting concerns out of band and return the response quicker.

What confuses me is what happens under the covers with the Rails instances.

I would guess that the Rails instance will not be ready to handle another request until all the threads spawned have finished executing?

Comment: What version of Ruby?  What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: i think that the behaviour is dependant of the server, the rails version, your configuration and the ruby runtime you are using. so "guess"ing is a really good alternative...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this safely, you need to enable the threadsafe option in rails:

`config.threadsafe!`

Otherwise, results will probably be undefined (depending on what operations you perform).

In either case, Rails will *not* block on the threads before handling another request. For this to happen, you would have to call `#join` on the threads. The threads will happily continue processing in the background. If you are after something more specific, please post some code.

Note that normally a library such as `delayed_job` or `factory_girl` is used to provide background processing rather than instantiating threads yourself. See the documentation for the latter for a good argument on why you also use a ruby implementation with good threading support (I use JRuby) if you are doing this extensively.